# Spring tries to manage interface when it is not wanted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application connected to local MariaDB database. Problem with my code is that Spring tries to manage an interface when it is not meant to. Here are my classes that initiate the error:

**AppRepository.java** - This a simple interface extending `CrudRepository` from Spring. Spring
tries to create a bean of this type, even if it's not annotated by `@Repository` or anything similar and it isn't desired (that's at least what I think - there are three implementations for each `@Entity` in my application, see below).

```java
public interface AppRepository<Orm extends ObjectRelationalMapping> extends CrudRepository<Orm, Long> {
}
```

**ObjectRelationalMapping.java** - This is the interface that gets the `Not a managed type` error. This interface is cruicial for implementation of `@Service`s and `@`(`Rest`)`Controller`s in my application.

```java
public interface ObjectRelationalMapping {
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);
}
```

**AuthorOrm.java** - This is one of the three entities in my application. All of them implement `ObjectRelationalMapping` interface.

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Collection;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Author")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Table(name = "author")
public class AuthorOrm implements ObjectRelationalMapping {

    @Column(name = "author_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "author_seq", sequenceName = "author_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title_before_name")
    private String titleBeforeName;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "title_after_name")
    private String titleAfterName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Collection<BookOrm> writtenBooks;

}
```

```
...beginning lines omitted, nothing suspicious there...
2024-01-14T19:53:51.960+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-14T19:53:52.140+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2024-01-14T19:53:52.649+01:00  WARN 27795 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-01-14T19:53:52.886+01:00  WARN 27795 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository' defined in cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.AppRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: interface cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.orm.ObjectRelationalMapping
2024-01-14T19:53:52.887+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-14T19:53:52.889+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-14T19:53:52.891+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-01-14T19:53:52.892+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-01-14T19:53:52.903+01:00  INFO 27795 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-14T19:53:52.917+01:00 ERROR 27795 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository' defined in cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.AppRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: interface cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.orm.ObjectRelationalMapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:969) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.ServerApp.main(ServerApp.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface cz.cvut.fit.tjv.dousami3.sem.server.orm.ObjectRelationalMapping
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I was able to fix this problem annotating `ObjectRelationalMapping` with `@Entity` from JPA, but then error about missing table of name `object_relational_mapping` occured (I do not want to have table for this interface).

I have also tried numerous combinations of `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Inheritance` annotations with no success. I always got some of the `Missing table` or `Not a managed type` error.

I can, of course, post more code, but I think doing that is irrelevant. Of course, feel free to ask any questions about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it myself: Annotating `AppRepository` with `@NoRepositoryBean` has exactly the effect that I want:

**AppRepository.java** - modified

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AppRepository<Orm extends ObjectRelationalMapping> extends CrudRepository<Orm, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have spring-data-jpa as a dependency and  extend the CrudRepository there is no need for you to annotate it with @Repository because Spring will create a bean of that type automatically